# Add menu button from database

Tags: java, javafx, jdbc, while-loop, menu

I'm trying to add a menu button in java from a database. I have tables with names in it in PhpMyAdmin. Once you click on the button a list shows up with all the names from the database. It seems like this doesn't work. Could anyone help me with this? I've tried different methods but it seems like it hasn't really worked.

```
try {
     Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
     conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/bibliotheek?user=root");
     Connection con = conn;

     ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT naam from klanten");

     while (rs.next()) {
         UserModel usr = new UserModel();
         usr.setNaam(rs.getString("naam"));
     }

     dropdownKlant.getItems().addAll(new MenuItem("naam"));

  } catch (SQLException sqlf) {
      System.out.println(sqlf.getMessage());
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

My FXML:

```
@FXML
private MenuButton dropdownKlant;
```

My user model:

```
public class UserModel {

    private int id;
    private String naam;
    private String achternaam;
    private String wachtwoord;
    private String woonplaats;
    private String straatnaam;
    private String straatnummer;


    public UserModel(int id, String naam, String achternaam, String wachtwoord, String woonplaats, String straatnaam, String straatnummer) {
        this.id = id;
        this.naam = naam;
        this.achternaam = achternaam;
        this.wachtwoord = wachtwoord;

        this.woonplaats = woonplaats;
        this.straatnaam = straatnaam;
        this.straatnummer = straatnummer;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setNaam(String naam) {
        this.naam = naam;
    }

    public void setAchternaam(String achternaam) {
        this.achternaam = achternaam;
    }

    public void setWachtwoord(String wachtwoord) {
        this.wachtwoord = wachtwoord;
    }

    public void setWoonplaats(String woonplaats) {
        this.woonplaats = woonplaats;
    }

    public void setStraatnaam(String straatnaam) {
        this.straatnaam = straatnaam;
    }

    public void setStraatnummer(String straatnummer) {
        this.straatnummer = straatnummer;
    }

    public UserModel() {

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getNaam() {
        return naam;
    }

    public String getAchternaam() {
        return achternaam;
    }

    public String getWachtwoord() {
        return wachtwoord;
    }

    public String getWoonplaats() {
        return woonplaats;
    }

    public String getStraatnaam() {
        return straatnaam;
    }

    public String getStraatnummer() {
        return straatnummer;
    }
}
```

Comment: you create a new user i the loop of result, but never use it, and after you create only one menuitme

Answer (score 1):

You don't add newly created [`MenuItem`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/MenuItem.html) to the [`Menu`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Menu.html). Create a temporary variable to let insert the newly created `MenuItem`. You might want to add an event handler as well to handle the on click event on the menu item because in the next iteration you lose the reference to it.

```
while (rs.next()) {
     UserModel usr = new UserModel();
     String naam = rs.getString("naam");
     usr.setNaam(naam);

     MenuItem temp = new MenuItem(naam);
     dropdownKlant.getItems().addAll(temp);
}
```

Alternatively, you might want to store these created `MenuItem` to a separate `List` and handle them later.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work :( I tried it with an action event too

Comment: What is `it doesn't work`? What is the result? Any error? Have you tried to debug through the while-iteration?

Comment: I have no errors so far and I don't really know how to do debugging, I can send the full code if you have to

Comment: Use print in loop to check your DB really gives you result

Comment: @Javaprogrammern00b also check, if the `MenuButton` is in a scene that is displayed. In the button click do `System.out.println(dropdownKlant.getItems().size() + "\n" + dropdownKlant.getScene().getWindow().isShowing());` after the try/catch